# How to Add Hours to Selected Time in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and jQuery, I Have three fields FromTime, Working hrs and To Time. If i Select from time 10:00 and Working Hrs 03:00 then Expected Result is 02:00 into To Time.

```
<select name="timestart">
<option value="00:00">00:00 am</option>
<option value="00:30">00:30 am</option>
<option value="01:00">01:00 am</option>
</select>
```

only add hrs to selected time.

Comment: Please explain how your posted HTML relates to your question as stated. Also, if you're having an issue with JS code, please post what you have tried so far, and what issues you have run into. If an incorrect value is being populated, what is it? State what isn't working.

Comment: Use moment.js. http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Wouldn't be 10:00 + 3hrs = 01:00?

Comment: i use 3 time control. From Time, Working Hrs, To Time.If i select 10:00 from time and 03:00 working hrs then To time would be 01:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any third-party JS library to achieve what you want. Since you are not giving further information, I will assume that:

1. Times are internally represented in military time (i.e 10:00 pm = 22:00). For example, there would be an item like: `<option value="22:00">10:00 pm</option>`. The maximum representable time is 23:59.
2. The value of "working hours" cannot exceed 24 hours.

The following code returns the military time of adding a given time amount (in hours) to a given military time:

```
function addhrs(time, toadd) {
    var hh = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2), 10); //Get the hours
    var mm = parseInt(time.substr(3, 2), 10); //Get the minutes
    var ahh = parseInt(toadd.substr(0, 2), 10); //Get the hours to add
    var amm = parseInt(toadd.substr(3, 2), 10); //Get the minutes to add        
    var minutes = hh*60 + mm;
    var minutes_to_add = ahh*60 + amm;
    var result_minutes = (minutes + minutes_to_add) % 1440;  //Prevent total number of minutes to exceed the minutes in a day.

    var result_hours = Math.floor(result_minutes / 60);
    result_minutes -= result_hours * 60;

    return ('0'+result_hours).substr(-2) + ":" + ('0'+result_minutes).substr(-2); 

}

addhrs('22:00', '03:00'); //Returns: 01:00
addhrs('12:30', '01:30'); //Returns 14:00
addhrs('12:00', '24:00'); //Returns 12:00
addhrs('12:00', '12:00'); //Returns 00:00
```

Comment: If i pass addhrs('22:00', 03:30); then??

Comment: You asked for adding hours. Wait a second and I'll change the code.

Comment: ok, it's done. Remember to pass the amount to add as a string, in the format 'hh:mm'.